# what is the difference between "friends to invite" and "All friends" options in facebook invite

Tags: facebook

what is the difference between "friends to invite" and 
"All friends" options in facebook invite dialog box.

Answer (score 0):

friends to invite means you can invite your friends in your list,

All friends means a list of all your friends

Answer (score 0):

Friends to invite : you can choose explicitly which friends you want to invite

All friends : It is pretty verbose. You invite all the people who are friends with you.